# Calling two functions on same event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions that I would like to execute with an `.on change` event using jQuery. I thought i could bind two events to the same handler (obviously wrong as the following functions do not work in conjunction with each other)

The function `file_extension_check` will run but not `file_size_check`, though if i swap them around then the last declared function works.. Which makes sense, I just don't understand how I can get them both to work together.

Another issue I have is that i can forsee is having them run together no matter the order in which they are run, so if file size validation fails, but then you upload an incorrect file extension but correct size, how could i get the correct error message to show.

```js
$(document).on('change', '.document_file_field', function() {
   var input = $(this);
   file_size_check(input);
 });

 // Functions to run to check file extension
 $(document).on('change', '.document_file_field', function() {
   var input_field = $(this);
   file_extension_check(input_field);
 });

 var file_extension_check = function(input_field) {
   console.log("file extension function fired");
   var file_name = input_field.val();
   var extension = file_name.replace(/^.*\./, '');
   extension.toLowerCase();
   var validExtensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'docx', 'mp4', 'pdf'];

   if ($.inArray(extension, validExtensions) == -1) {
     input_field.prev('.custom-file-upload.btn').removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-danger');
     input_field.parent('.upload_document').find('.js-error').text(extension + ' file formats are not allowed');
     input_field.parent('.upload_document').find('.btn-success').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   } else {
     input_field.prev('.custom-file-upload.btn').removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-info');
     input_field.parent('.upload_document').find('.js-error').empty();
     input_field.parent('.upload_document').find('.btn-success').removeAttr('disabled');

   }

 }

 var file_size_check = function(input) {
   console.log("file size function fired");
   var raw_file_size = input[0].files[0].size
   var file_size_mb = (Math.round((raw_file_size / 1024 / 1024) * 100) / 100)

   if (raw_file_size >= 1000000) {
     input.prev('.custom-file-upload.btn').removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-danger');
     input.parent('.upload_document').find('.js-error').text('File Size to large - Must be under 1mb');
     input.parent('.upload_document').find('.btn-success').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   } else {
     input.prev('.custom-file-upload.btn').removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-info');
     input.parent('.upload_document').find('.js-error').empty();
     input.parent('.upload_document').find('.btn-success').removeAttr('disabled');
   }
 }
```

```css
.custom-file-upload {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}
.btn-info {
  background: blue;
}
.btn-danger {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="upload_document">
  <label class="custom-file-upload btn btn-info" for="document_media"></label>
  <input type="file" id="document_media" class="document_file_field"></input>
  </br>

  <input class="btn-success" type="submit">Submit</input>
  <div class="js-error"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Note that `.toLowerCase()` does not modify the string, it returns a **new** string, so you need `extension = extension.toLowerCase();`

Comment: why not just run one after the other in the same callback?

Comment: Also you can add `console.log()` calls to the event handlers to see whether they're being called (and, assuming there aren't errors, they will be).

Comment: @Mathletics I tried that, but still had same problem... its strange as i thought it would work

Comment: The order they run *does* relate to the order they are registered, but both will run. What order do you want?

Comment: Each function is overridding the results of the other!

Comment: Note (not necessarily to the OP, who may already have plans to do this): validating file type by extension testing is not a way to prevent unwanted/invalid uploads. It's *helpful*, and so it isn't a bad idea, but your server-side code should do some work to make sure that what purports to be a ".jpg" file really is one. There are all sorts of potential exploits via image viewer software of unknown quality (in terms of security).

Comment: Thanks @Pointy, yes there will be server side validation, this is just meant to highlight for the user that they have made an error with file size or type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To combine these methods just wrap it all up in a single method, checking all possible failures. This should work:

```js
$(document).on('change', '.document_file_field', function() {
   var input = $(this);
   file_size_extension_check(input);
 });


 var file_size_extension_check = function(input) {
   console.log("function fired");
   var file_name = input.val();
   var extension = file_name.replace(/^.*\./, '').toLowerCase();
   var validExtensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'docx', 'mp4', 'pdf'];

   // check if the extension is valid
   var extensionValid = $.inArray(extension, validExtensions) >= 0;
   
   // check if the size is valid
   var raw_file_size = input[0].files[0].size;
   var sizeValid = raw_file_size < 1000000;
   
   // create messages
   var messages = [];
   if(!sizeValid) messages.push("File Size to large - Must be under 1mb.");
   if(!extensionValid) messages.push(extension + ' file formats are not allowed.');
   
   // if either are invalid show the errors, otherwise dont
   if (!sizeValid || !extensionValid) {
     input.prev('.custom-file-upload.btn').removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-danger');
     input.parent('.upload_document').find('.js-error').text(messages.join(' '));
     input.parent('.upload_document').find('.btn-success').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   } else {
     input.prev('.custom-file-upload.btn').removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-info');
     input.parent('.upload_document').find('.js-error').empty();
     input.parent('.upload_document').find('.btn-success').removeAttr('disabled');

   }

 }
```

```css
.custom-file-upload {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}
.btn-info {
  background: blue;
}
.btn-danger {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="upload_document">
  <label class="custom-file-upload btn btn-info" for="document_media"></label>
  <input type="file" id="document_media" class="document_file_field"></input>
  </br>

  <input class="btn-success" type="submit">Submit</input>
  <div class="js-error"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, this is what i originally had, but still the `file_extension_check` function is all that runs

Comment: Putting a `console.log` in both methods will show that both are running - I suspect you're only getting the *output* from one displayed as they both use the same elements for display

Comment: what im trying to achieve is to make them independent of each other. is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by *independent of each other*? You want both "validations" to show output to the user?

Comment: well imagine this scenario please, I add an image that is over 1mb, that should invoke `file_size_check`, and display error message, then say i upload a wrong file type, that should clear the last error out and invoke `file_extension_check`..I would like it if the order in which they are run doesnt matter..Am i asking or looking at this incorrectly? and a further scenario could be both validations fail so i would need to output both error messages

Answer (score 1):

You've only got one error message field. If your input is invalid in both ways, then you'll only see one of the errors.

Combine them as in the above answer, but also clear out the error before starting:

```
$(document).on('change', '.document_file_field', function(event) {
   var input = $(this);
   input.parent('.upload_document').find('.js-error').empty();
   file_size_check(input);
   file_extension_check(input);
 });
```

Then inside the validator functions:

```
if ($.inArray(extension, validExtensions) == -1) {
  input_field.prev('.custom-file-upload.btn').removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-danger');
  var errorMsg = input_field.parent('.upload_document').find('.js-error');
  errorMsg.append($("<div/>", {
    text: extension + ' file formats are not allowed');
  }));
  input_field.parent('.upload_document').find('.btn-success').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

(and similarly for the other one.) Changes along those lines will mean that each check *adds* its message to the error box, in my example inside `<div>` elements. (You might want to make the error box a `<ul>` and add `<li>` elements; it's up to your design.)

Answer (score 1):

Each function is overridding the results of the other so no matter what happens the last to run will win and you'll never see the result of the first.  By changing each function to return a boolean you can make sure you only call the second if the first has passed.

```
$(document).on('change', '.document_file_field', function() {
   var input = $(this);
   if(file_size_check(input)) {
       file_extension_check(input_field);
   }
 });

var file_extension_check = function(input_field) {
  var file_name = input_field.val();
  var extension = file_name.replace(/^.*\./, '');
  extension.toLowerCase();
  var validExtensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'docx', 'mp4', 'pdf'];

  if ($.inArray(extension, validExtensions) == -1) {
    input_field.prev('.custom-file-upload.btn').removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-danger');
    input_field.parent('.upload_document').find('.js-error').text(extension + ' file formats are not allowed');
    input_field.parent('.upload_document').find('.btn-success').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    return false;
  } else {
    input_field.prev('.custom-file-upload.btn').removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-info');
    input_field.parent('.upload_document').find('.js-error').empty();
    input_field.parent('.upload_document').find('.btn-success').removeAttr('disabled');
    return true;
 }

}

var file_size_check = function(input) {
  var raw_file_size = input[0].files[0].size
  var file_size_mb = (Math.round((raw_file_size / 1024 / 1024) * 100) / 100)

  if (raw_file_size >= 1000000) {
    input.prev('.custom-file-upload.btn').removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-danger');
    input.parent('.upload_document').find('.js-error').text('File Size to large - Must be under 1mb');
    input.parent('.upload_document').find('.btn-success').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    return false;
 } else {
    input.prev('.custom-file-upload.btn').removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-info');
    input.parent('.upload_document').find('.js-error').empty();
    input.parent('.upload_document').find('.btn-success').removeAttr('disabled'); 
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however (and maybe im looking at this wrong or trying to achieve something that's not handled in the way i am trying to do) but I would like them to act independent of each other, not wanting them to rely on each other if i can..So its not neccesary for one function to call only if another has passed

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your upload button should only be enabled if both validations are true, so you could return "true" for each and enable the button if both are true, like so:

```
$(document).on('change', '.document_file_field', function(event){
var input = $(this);
var size = file_size_check(input); // returns true if valid
var extension = file_extension_check(input); // returns true if valid
if(size && extension){ $('.btn-success').removeAttr('disabled'); }
});
```